# Visual Studio Code Default Folder

Tags: visual-studio-code, settings

I recently installed Visual Studio Code to just touch stuff up on my laptop when I work with friends on projects, and I've been wondering how to set a default directory for the folder. It's kind of annoying to have to set the folder every time I open the editor.

Comment: There is an open GH issue tracking this at [microsoft/vscode/issues/115730](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/115730#issuecomment-991705914)

Answer (score 0):

Here what VS Code says:

```
// An explicit start path where the terminal will be launched, this is used as the current working directory (cwd) for the shell process. This may be particularly useful in workspace settings if the root directory is not a convenient cwd.
```

So, you have to edit this variable:

```
 "terminal.integrated.cwd": ""
```

For instance on Gnu-Linux/Unix like:

```
 "terminal.integrated.cwd": "/home/oldman/C#/ASP.MVC"
```

On Windows

```
 "terminal.integrated.cwd": "C:\Users\oldman\C#\ASP.MVC"
```

Your terminals will be set at this current working directory (cwd) **as for your root directory** in the explorer, (here "/home/oldman/C#/ASP.MVC" on linux, and "C:\Users\oldman\C#\ASP.MVC").

Comment: This answer references running a terminal from within VS Code, which is different than opening a default folder.

Answer (score 0):

autohotkey can help

add a hotkey to this

```
vscode_wf:= "C:\Users\noway\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\code.exe"
Run, %vscode_wf% "D:\markdown_folder", ,Max
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to your VS Code shortcut, right-click it then go to "Properties".
After the path of VS Code, insert the path of your folder

image showing the instruction above:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if I have understood the question correctly, but the following comes to mind.

- Add Visual Studio Code to Your Context Menu and open any folder directly with a simple click.
- Adapt your settings to control how windows are being reopened after starting vscode i.e. `"window.restoreWindows": "all"`
- Install an extension like [Reopen Folder](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=winebarrel.reopen-folder)

Hope this helps you.